# Batch File See Update When Txt File Is Changed

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a TXT file that is generated by my BackSpace47.bat with the code of

```
set /p SomeVar=Enter Some Text Please: 
echo %SomeVar% >BSpace.txt
pause
```

I need a Batch file that can check if the BSpace.txt has changed from the previous entry of BackSpace47.bat after it displays it once. If it hasn't changed then it needs to ignore it. If the text has changed display the new text. I have tried this and failed mutiple times I have created infinite loops and crashed my pc a lot of times XD. I figured I would ask the pros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be approached by use of a controlled statement to continually Check the contents of the text file and check if a condition is met.

```
 @echo off

 Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

 :up

  If exist previouscontent.txt (

 call :check bspace.txt previouscontent.txt

 )





 For /f "tokens=*" %%a in (bspace.txt) do (

 set previouscontent=%%a & echo !previouscontent!>previouscontent.txt



 )

Goto up

 :check

 For /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%~1) do (

 For /f "tokens=*" %%# in (%~2) do (

 If "%%#"=="%%a" (

 Echo content not changed! [  %%a / %# ]

 ) else (

Echo content changed! [ %%a / %%# ]

 )


 )

 )

Echo  End of code 

 Pause
```